# Reproject and resample raster1 to CRS and grid of raster2, but keeping the shape of the original raster

Tags: python, rasterio, resampling, transform

I am working with two raster files.
path_target: shape (27502, 6133); CRS: EPSG 31255
wk_path: shape (294825, 570431); CRS: EPSG 31287

I would like to reproject path_target to EPSG 31287 and align the grid to that one of wk_path, but don't use the width and height wk_path rather of the original file. It was possible for me to transform yet I have the problem that the cells of the reprojected raster missalign with that on of wk_path.

[image: black/gray pixel are of the reprojected layer and the sandy colour of wk_path]

Here the code I used:

```
def changeProjection(path_target, path_wk):
    # naming 
    org_name = os.path.split(path_target)[-1][:-4] 
    rep_name = org_name + "_TEST_31287"
    rep_path = os.path.join(dirname, "reproject")
    rep_out = os.path.join(rep_path, rep_name +".tif")
    if os.path.exists(rep_out): return(rep_out, rep_name)
    from rasterio.warp import calculate_default_transform, reproject, Resampling
    with rasterio.open(path_target) as src:
        src_crs = src.crs
        src_transform = src.transform
        src_arr = src.read(1)
        # Calculate the transformation parameters and output dimensions
        #https://pygis.io/docs/e_raster_resample.html
        with rasterio.open(path_wk) as wk: 
            dst_crs = wk.crs
            dst_transform, dst_width, dst_height = calculate_default_transform(
                src_crs,
                dst_crs, 
                src.width,
                src.height, 
                *src.bounds,
                dst_resolution=wk.res[0],)
            #Create a new raster in the target CRS
            dst_kwargs = src.meta.copy()
            dst_kwargs.update({
                'driver': 'GTiff',
                'dtype': src_arr.dtype,
                'count': 1,
                'width': dst_width,
                'height': dst_height,
                'crs': dst_crs,
                'transform': dst_transform,
                'nodata': src.nodata,
                'compress': 'lzw',
                })    
            # Reproject the source raster to the target CRS
            #https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/reproject.html
        
            # Write the new raster to disk
            with rasterio.open(rep_out, 'w', **dst_kwargs) as dst:
                for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                    reproject(
                        source=src_arr,
                        destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                        src_transform=src_transform,
                        src_crs=src_crs,
                        dst_transform=dst_transform,
                        dst_crs=dst_crs,
                        resampling=Resampling.nearest)
    return(rep_out, rep_name)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could calculate the difference between the upper left coordinates of the two rasters and subtract/add from/to the upper left coordinates newly projected layer.

Comment: Thanks i get your idea, but it seems i am not getting there. 
So what tried instead is: take the bbox of my wk (left:  112565.9147) and of target after i did a rasterio.warp.transform_bounds (left: 518828.5901956975). Since the transformed bounds have way more decimals, therefore i rounded it to also 4 decimal places. 

dst_transform_new = rasterio.Affine(dst_transform[0], dst_transform[1], round(dst_transform[2],4),dst_transform[3], dst_transform[4], round(dst_transform[5],4))
Then i used "dst_transform_new " for my resampling but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally managed to find a solution for my Problem.

- I used "rasterio.warp.transform_bounds" to get the new bound for my
  target raster.
- The bounds (as Polygone) are then used to mask WK
- Then the transfom settings were used for the resample of the target raster
- in the end the target raster and WK raster aligned exactly

```py
def reprojectnDSM(path_target, path_wk, org_name):
    # naming sachen
    rep_name = org_name + "_31287"
    rep_path = os.path.join(dirname, "reproject")
    rep_out = os.path.join(rep_path, rep_name +".tif")
    rep_out_wk = rep_out.replace("ndsm","wk")
    if os.path.exists(rep_out) and os.path.exists(rep_out_wk) : return(rep_out, rep_name, rep_out_wk)
    from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
    with rasterio.open(path_target) as src:
        src_arr = src.read(1)
        # Calculate the transformation parameters and output dimensions
        with rasterio.open(path_wk) as wk:            
            from shapely.geometry import box
            import geopandas as gpd
            import rasterio.mask as mask
            # create bounding box 
            bounds = rasterio.warp.transform_bounds(src.crs,wk.crs,*src.bounds)
            shape = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id":1,"geometry":[box(*bounds)]})
            shape.crs = wk.crs
            out_image, out_transform = mask.mask(wk, shape["geometry"],all_touched=True, crop=True)
            # hier wird die gecroppte WK gleich rausgeschrieben
            out_meta = wk.meta.copy()
            out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "transform": out_transform,
                 "compress": 'lzw'
                 })
            with rasterio.open(rep_out_wk, "w", **out_meta) as crop_wk:
                crop_wk.write(out_image)
            #Create a new raster in the target CRS
            dst_kwargs = src.profile.copy()
            dst_kwargs.update({
                'width': out_image.shape[2],
                'height': out_image.shape[1],
                'crs': wk.crs,
                'transform': out_transform,
                'compress': 'lzw',
                'BIGTIFF':'YES'
                })
            # Reproject the source raster to the target CRS
            # Write the new raster to disk
            with rasterio.open(rep_out, 'w', **dst_kwargs) as dst:
                for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                    reproject(
                        source=src_arr,
                        destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                        src_transform=src.transform,
                        src_crs=src.crs,
                        src_nodata=src.nodata,
                        dst_transform=out_transform,
                        dst_crs=wk.crs,
                        resampling=Resampling.bilinear)
    return(rep_out, rep_name, rep_out_wk)
```

Comment: please accept this as answer.